# How do I send a local variable to a partial rendered only after a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a Bootstrap Modal that is triggered when this link is clicked:

```
<a class="plus" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">&nbsp;</a>
```

I then have this in my `_footer.html.erb`

```
<%= render 'shared/tag_users_modal' %>
```

Which then has this standard Bootstrap Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal tagging fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tag User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                <%= simple_form_for @node, url: add_tagged_user_node_path(@node), method: :post do |f| %>
                  <%= f.error_notification %>

                  <div class="form-inputs">
                        <%= f.input_field :user, label: "Users", collection: @users, as: :check_boxes, checked: @node.user_tags %>
                  </div>                            

                  <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work because `@node` is nil - i.e. it wasn't passed. I can't pass that variable from my `_footer` partial, so I want to be able to pass it in the original execution of the modal.

How do I do that? Or how do I do this in another way?

**Edit 1**

To add more context, The initial link that is calling the Bootstrap Modal is actually in another partial that had a local variable of `node` passed to it also. That one is called like this:
    <%= render partial: "shared/box", locals: {node: node} %>

But I need to continue the execution of the modal being fired only after that toggle link is clicked in that first `shared/box`.

In summary:
 - `/shared/box` partial has original link that fires BS modal.
 - `/shared/footer' contains a render of another partial`tag_users_modal`.
 -`/shared/tag_users_modal`contains the modal, but I need the`@node`object passed to it and the`add_tagged_user_node_path` to work.

Now it doesn't get passed, because I can't figure out a way to get the original `node: node` to the third partial in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this reason, it is best to use local variables instead of instance variables in your partials.

```
# your main view file:
<%= render partial: path_to_partial, locals: {bool: true} %>

# your partial:
<%= bool ? 1 : 2 %>
```

With those options, the partial will display 1.

Also, an alternative to passing local variables as the `locals` option is to use `render` instead of `render partial` like so:

```
# your main view file:
<%= render path_to_partial, bool: true %>
```

From the above, you can infer that you must change `@node` in your partial to `node` and specify `{node: @node}` wherever you are rendering the partial.

Comment: I understand that, but that's not the issue here. What's happening is my partial is stored in the `shared` directory, and that partial is called from another partial in the `shared` directory. That partial was called with a local variable of `node: node`, but because I am passing the execution to a modal that is only fired when that above link is clicked, I have no way of passing that `node: node` to the partial that renders the pop-up/modal after the link is clicked. I hope that was more clear. If this were a standard view in a standard controller, your suggestion would work. But it's not :(

Comment: I added more details so you can get more clarity on what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: First, remove all instance variable from your partials. And just use local variables. This is just general advice. But ultimately, the problem, as you define it, is that you simply don't have a variable that you want to use. There is no 'solution' to this. You would have to repopulate the variable before you can use it. Perhaps you can store something as a param in the link that will help you in re-finding `node` when the link is clicked and the controller action is called.

Comment: Ok yes, that's a good potential solution. So I guess that brings me to the next logical question, how do I convert this: `<a class="plus" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">&nbsp;</a>`, into a Rails link that will do that. Pass the local variable `node` as a param. That's kinda what I am trying to figure out how to do, sorry if it wasn't explained properly...been staring at this a while :|

Comment: If clicking on that link displays the modal without an AJAX request, then the contents of the modal are already rendered on the page, just hidden, and the `node` variable should be available.

Comment: You may be right, because now I am getting this error: `undefined method 'keys' for #<Node:0x007fcdb32cf4b0>`, yet I have no call to `keys` in my partials.